# Spherical electrode diffusion problem; trying to get to planar system

Tags: calculus

I'm working through the derivation of current in a spherical electrode, and so far I've been able to get it into the following, starting from Fick's 2nd Law:
[image: image of problem]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta c$ is a function of (among other things) $r$, so you can't just swap $v/r$ into the differentiation operator. Instead you have to use the quotient rule for differentiating to get:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2vr^{-1}}{\text{d} r^2}+\frac{2\text{d}vr^{-1}}{r\text{d} r}-\frac{svr^{-1}}{D}=0$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}\left(\frac{v'}{r}-\frac{v}{r^2}\right)+\frac{2}{r}\left(\frac{v'}{r}-\frac{v}{r^2}\right)-\frac{sv}{rD}=0$$
$$\left(\frac{v''}{r}-\frac{v'}{r^2}\right)-\left(\frac{v'}{r^2}-\frac{2v}{r^3}\right)+\frac{2}{r}\left(\frac{v'}{r}-\frac{v}{r^2}\right)-\frac{sv}{rD}=0$$
Then a bunch of stuff cancels, and we're let with

$$\frac{v''}{r}-\frac{sv}{rD}=\frac{1}{r}\left(v''-\frac{sv}{D}\right)=0$$

And, since we know that $r\neq0$, we're done.